# How to disable Secure Boot in Asus Z97i Plus to dual boot Ubuntu / Windows 8.1?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, asus

In Windows 8.1, I created a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I've installed ubuntu on a partition of the SSD drive. Win 8 is installed on a different partition of that SSD.

Problem: the only way to boot into Ubuntu for me is to insert the bootable usb drive, go into the BIOS, and select boot from USB. In this way I can access Ubuntu OS and even use it (typing from it atm).

I think I've tried everything to make it work :

1. update BIOS to latest from Asus : 2502
2. in BIOS disable Fast Boot
3. in Asus BIOS Secure Boot : Enabled is greyed out and cannot be edited
4. Go into the Security of the BIOS and set Admin password and User password.
5. Restart computer and enter password on request
6. Secure Boot is still greyed out and can't be disabled.

As I understand it there is no way to make dual boot work properly without disabling Secure Boot. To be honest I'm a bit disappointed with Asus because it seems this problem is specific to their motherboards.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Contact Asus.  Complain bitterly.  Ask them for a date when this problem will be solved. Insist on a date. :-(

Comment: my "fix" is that I have my ubuntu boot usb always plugged in at the back of my computer... in fact I could remove it because I restart my pc once a week